# Mod-rewrite rule which just gets the part of the URL after the =

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm currently trying to redirect this URL

```
http://dev.example.org/active/researchers/contact.php?IDENT=12345
```

to

```
http://portaldev.example.org/users/ident/12345
```

in htaccess.

However, I can only get a redirect to

```
http://portaldev.example.org/users/ident/IDENT=12345
```

because I can't find a way to get rid of the `IDENT=`. How can I do that?

The rewrite conditions in my htaccess are:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/active/researchers/contact\.php$ 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^IDENT=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://portaldev.example.org/users/ident/$2 [R=302,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)IDENT=(\d+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?active/researchers/contact\.php$  http://portaldev.example.org/users/ident/%1 [R=302,QSD,NC]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but your code doesn't work for me as it doesn't redirect at all. I'm using a site to test the code called https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and it said the condition is not met but regardless I tried it on my site but got no redirect.

Comment: I fail to understand your point. If I test above rule set it works for me as desired when using the test site you suggested. The only thing I just added: the ``QSD`` flag to remove the original parameter during the rewrite process. But certainly the condition _does_ match and a redirection _is_ performed. Maybe you made a mistake while copying above rule set?

Comment: Yh sorry my bad seems like it does work, not sure what went wrong but i found my answer anyway, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer to my question for anyone else who needs help:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/active/researchers/contact\.php$ 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^IDENT=(.*)
RewriteRule (.*)  http://portaldev.cepr.org/users/ident/%1? [R=301,L]
```

I think the main thing was the ? at the end of the rewrite rule but it also wouldn't work unless I put in the first RewriteCond to request uri and used (.*) in the rewrite rule